# What's special about port 6000?

Tags: macos, web, flask

Start your Mac. Take the base Flask app from the [quickstart page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/), and change the port to 6000, which gives you the following:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(port=6000)
```

Save this in a file named e.g. `test.py`. Then create a virtualenv, run `pip install flask`, and call `test.py`. Here is what you will see on the terminal:

```
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:6000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

So Flask claims to have bound to port 6000. Now start a browser and navigate to `localhost:6000`. I was expecting to see the silly message `Hello World`, which is the case when I leave out the `port` argument to `run`, and navigate to `localhost:5000`. But here is what I see instead:

[image]

Now do `Ctrl-C` on the terminal, and stop the running process. Change the port to 6001, rerun the command. `Hello World` is back! How can this be? There are no other processes connecting to port 6000; `lsof -i | grep 6000` returns 0 results, and if there were any processes, Flask would fail to bind to that port in the first place. Firewall is turned off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox gives a slightly different and more informative answer: 

"This address uses a network port which is normally used for purposes other than web browsing. Firefox has canceled the request for your protection."

Comment: Interesting. It looks like port 6000 has caused a number of major security issues, maybe browsers block it because of that? http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=6000

Comment: The plot thickens! I can actually access http://localhost:6000 with wget, which successfully fetches `Hello World`. Apears to be a browser thing.

Comment: Is this a typo or you try to access port 5000?

Comment: @Thomas I want the app to bind to 6000 (which works) and access it with the browser on http://localhost:6000 (which does not work). With port 5000 (the default in Flask), everything works.

Comment: So on 3 Sept 2023 this is still the case.  Frustrating because Chrome was so un-informative on it's error.  Firefox helped me pick another port.  I guess every developer needs to pick 6000 and learn that that's not a port to use for experimenting with a web app (that port is used by X11 for GUI traffic).   Note that `curl  http://localhost:6000` worked just fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, found the answer. Browsers block certain ports, although they are not in the system port range, some of them in the ranges widely used for local web development. [The links in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22622633/1285782) point to the rationale from the browser vendors and exhaustive lists. As the germans say, "Wieder was gelernt".

Thx to @glyphobet for his comment that led to the right answer.