# Websockets on Phonegap Android

Tags: android, websocket, phonegap

I am trying to use Websockets to connect to a specific port. I have tried the code below but get the error:

**Error: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The port 23 is not allowed.**

```
var socket1 = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.4.1" + ":23");
```

Is there something in the security that has to be set up to allow my port number?

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving that error because the port 23 it's reserved for Telnet.

You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314070/7673764).

A complete list can be found on this link:

- http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/PortBanning.html

Comment: This is for a special device not a server that I am communicating with. Is there anyway around it? I have used sockets-for-cordova but I am having some problems so I wanted to try Websockets to rule out what is causing the problem.

Comment: @MarkA.Rupert since it's not a server, and as I see you're working inside a local network, have you opened the port 23 in your router?

Comment: I never worked with websockets between two devices, but if that is not working, one of the problems could be that your router may be blocking the communication

Comment: The device I am connecting to has its own server. In effect it is the router. There is no router in between. I am guessing the Websockets is just blocking port 23 as suggested above. I am using sockets-for-cordova and that is working.

Comment: Have you tried to use another port, like 3000, to communicate between the Websockets? If sockets-for-cordova it's working on the port 23, probably Websockets have some problem using that port.